# Splitting two strings and rejoining

Tags: c#

I am currently working on an address selector for a checkout process, this currently has a function that adds a comma after all fields that are found on the check out like this.

[image]

This is done using,

```
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Join(", ", lines.ToArray()), address.ID.ToString()));
```

This is fine until you add a name in, which is a must have so they may use their account to delivery to a different person in the case of gifts or if you wish to order something and have someone else sign for the product. I wish for my first/last name to not have a comma between them, however... I can't simply do this by not adding a comma on the first two fields as there is many cases in which a name would not be entered on the delivery address.

This is how it displays currently
[image]

I was thinking the best way to do this was to split the name into a separate string and then the rest of the address into another, add the commas in and then rejoin the strings into one.

If anyone could think of a better way to do this, please share your ideas.

Comment: Why not just create a `FullName` property that appends the last name to the first and then use this?

Comment: That was basically my idea, I just worded it badly.

Comment: Have you tried it? Seems like it would work...

Comment: About to give it a shot, will update.

Comment: Have updated if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this method,

```
  StringBuilder fullName = new StringBuilder();

            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.Name))
                fullName.AppendFormat("{0} ", address.Name);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.Name1))
                fullName.AppendFormat("{0} ", address.Name1);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.Name2))
                fullName.Append(address.Name2);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName.ToString()))
                lines.Add(fullName.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

1 You can also use

```
string.Concat(lines.ToArray()).Replace(" ",",");
```

2 Or iterate with foreach and build stringBuilder

Answer (score -1):

```
String = String.Replace(","," ");
```

or

```
String = String.Replace(","," ");
```

This will do what you want.